# How do you make a instance of an external class in python

Tags: python, class, module, instance, external

If I have Main.py

```
import Test
test = Test()
test.test_func()
```

And Test.py

```
class Test:
    def test_func(self):
        print("success")
```

it throws an error 'module' object is not callable

I have spent hours trying to figure this out. If I put the class in Main.py I can get an instance of the class but I can't get it to work externally.

Comment: You need to `from Test import Test` **or** `test = Test.Test()`. Yes, you are going to have to learn Python if you want to use it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, got it..

Answer (score 1):

You have imported the Test module but you are constructing the module and not the inner class. Try changing it to `test = Test.Test()`

Comment: Oh my gosh your the best!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the class declared within module `Test`. Change Main.py to:

```
import Test
test = Test.Test()
test.test_func()
```

or

```
from Test import Test
test = Test()
test.test_func()
```